# Why is putImageData so slow?

Tags: performance, html, canvas

I am working with a relatively large Canvas where various (complex) stuff is drawn to. I then want to save the Canvas' state, so I can quickly reset it to the state it now is at a later point. I use getImageData for this and store the data in a variable. I then draw some more stuff to the canvas and will later reset the Canvas to where it was when I saved it's state, using putImageData.

However, it turns out, that putImageData is very slow. Infact, it is slower than simply redrawing the entire Canvas from scratch, which involves several drawImage covering most of the surface, and over 40.000 lineTo operations followed up by strokes and fills.

Redrawing the approx 2000 x 5000 pixel canvas from scratch takes ~ 170ms, using putImageData though  takes whopping 240ms. Why is putImageData so slow compared to redrawing the canvas, although redrawing the canvas involves filling nearly the entire canvas with drawImage and then again filling roughly 50% of the canvas with polygons using lineTo, stroke and fill. So basicly every single pixel ist touched at least once when redrawing.

Because drawImage seems to be so much faster then putImageData (after all, the drawImage part of redrawing the canvas takes less than 30 ms).  I decided to try to save the state of the canvas not using getImageData, but instead using canvas.toDataURL and then creating an Image from the data URL which I would stick into drawImage to draw it to the canvas. Turns out this whole procedure is much faster and only takes roughly 35ms to complete.

So why is putImageData so much slower then the alternatives (using getDataURL or simply redrawing)? How could I speed things up further? Is there and if, what is in general the best way to store the state of a canvas?

(All the numbers are measured using Firebug from within Firefox)

Comment: It would be interesting if you could post a demonstration of your problem online somewhere. In noVNC (http://github.com/kanaka/noVNC)  I use putImageData for lots of small and medium size image data arrays and I don't see a performance problem with putImageData. Perhaps you are running into a specific pessimal performance case that should be bug'd.

Comment: You can have a look here http://www.danielbaulig.de/A3O/ It will not work 100% if the firebug console is switched of, so make sure to switch it on. The version checked out is the one using putImageData. You can trigger it by clicking on any "tile". It will refresh the buffer canvas using putImageData and then "highlight" the selcted tile. In a3o_oo.js there are some lines commented out, that can be used to switch between using putImageData (current), using getDataURL (the two lines mentioning this.boardBuffer) and plain redrawing (the drawBoard line) of the buffer canvas.

Comment: Great question and great solutions. But did you ever find out the real reason why putImageData is so slow compared to drawImage?

Comment: @cherouvim No, not really. My assumption is that the major reason is that the ImageData structure is no longer managed in hardware accelerated graphics structures and thus calling getImageData/putImageData will have to translate to/from these objects, which is slow, involves copying lots of data, instantiating objects, etc, whereas using drawImage simply draws an already existing texture/drawing context to the screen - which with modern hardware is incredibly fast.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Just a small update on what the best way is to do this. I actually wrote my Bachelor Thesis on [High Performance ECMAScript and HTML5 Canvas](https://1drv.ms/b/s!Ao3uRCi2tDVwjnQgeZPFyyGPc60S?e=gcmZYw) (pdf, German; password: stackoverflow), so I gathered some expertise on this topic by now. The clearly best solution is to use multiple canvas elements. Drawing from one canvas onto another canvas is just as fast as drawing an arbitrary image to a canvas. Thus "storing" the state of a canvas is just as fast as restoring it later again when using two canvas elements.

[This jsPerf testcase](http://jsperf.com/buffering) shows the various approaches and their benefits and drawbacks very clearly.

Just for completeness, here how you really *should* do it:

```
// setup
var buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
buffer.width = canvas.width;
buffer.height = canvas.height;


// save
buffer.getContext('2d').drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

// restore
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(buffer, 0, 0);
```

This solution is, depending on browser, up to 5000x faster than the one getting the upvotes.

Comment: What if you need to store a lot of states in an array? Should one create an array of a bunch of canvases?? e.g. `var numBuffers = 20; var tmpCan = document.createElement('canvas'); var buffers = [tmpCan]; for (var i = 1, len = numBuffers, i < numBuffers; i++) { buffers.push(tmpCan.cloneNode()); }` or something like that?? **OR** is there a better solution?

Comment: The jsPerf link gives "This Serverless Function has crashed".

Comment: @JosephQuinsey It appears like jsperf.com is having issues. I am not sure if this is something intermittent or the site has stopped existing for good. You can find the actual source code I used for these performance test in my linked Bachelor Thesis above, too. The last two pages in the addendum contain the source code for the getImageData/putImageData as well as the intermediary canvas approach.

Answer (score 11):

In Firefox 3.6.8 I was able to workaround the slowness of putImageData by using toDataUrl/drawImage instead. For me it's working fast enough that I can call it within handling a mousemove event:

To save:

```
savedImage = new Image()
savedImage.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
```

The to restore:

```
ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
ctx.drawImage(savedImage,0,0)
```

Comment: Recognized your response just now. Infact I am currently doing it the exact same way :) Additionally I am currently experimenting with using an additional, hidden canvas as a buffer. This should increase performance creating the buffer, which is rather slow using toDataURL and drawing speed should remain about the same (since drawImage can also take a canvas element as an image).

Comment: Just realized that this answer keeps getting upvotes. I appreciate this answer, but the solution explained is actually terrible performance-wise. Please instead refer to the accepted answer by myself.

Comment: I am trying to draw to a canvas from pixel data stored in a Uint8Clamped array with better performance than putImageData. This seems like a promising way to achieve that. I should be able to convert the Uint8Clamped array into a DataURL, populate an Image object with that DataURL, and then draw that image to the canvas. I haven't tested it yet, but I am hoping it will be faster than putImageData.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you say you are measuring with Firebug.  I actually find that Firebug slows down JS execution considerably, so you may not be getting good numbers for performance.

As for `putImageData`, I suspect it's because the functions takes a large JS array containing many `Number` objects, all of which have to be checked for range (0..255) and copied into a native canvas buffer.

Maybe once the WebGL ByteArray types are available, this sort of thing can be made quicker.

It does seem odd that base64 decoding and uncompressing the data (with the PNG data URL) is quicker, but that only calls one JS function with one JS string, so it is using mostly native code and types.

Comment: since my numbers are for the most part from native code execution, I doubt that Firebug will have a significant effect on them. Nevertheless, we are not talking about fractions of milliseconds, but actually but actually a quarter of a second for basicly a single function call (putImageData). Bad performance due to the JS array might be. I'll check that by testing how fast JS can handle (copy, manipulate, etc) such an array outside of putImageData.

Comment: Continuation: Deocding, uncompressing,etc is not happening at the point where the canvas state is restored, but when it is saved. So this happens only once and I actually didn't measure it, because how long it takes to save the state is not of much concern. The critical part is restoring the canvas state. At that point I have the Image object long created. So if the Image object contains it's data in a native buffer, this indeed could be the cause of the problem (or better the lack of it for the drawImage approach).

Comment: I know that `putImageData` performance can be ok (80-100fps with a 480x320 buffer) - but you are dealing with very large images!

Comment: Ah, +1 for mentioning WebGL ByteArray. I've been looking for information about Javascript binary arrays and your comment helped me to find it. Here is the current discussion: http://www.listware.net/201009/w3c-public-webapps/21504-arraybuffer-and-bytearray-questions.html. And here is the proposed standard: https://cvs.khronos.org/svn/repos/registry/trunk/public/webgl/doc/spec/TypedArray-spec.html

Answer (score 2):

This is presumably because modern browsers use hardware acceleration for `<canvas>` elements, and `getImageData()`/`putImageData()` require transferring image data from the graphics card to the host or vice versa. That is notoriously slow.

Using two canvases will be faster because all the data stays on the graphics card.