# Convert Piece of canvas to DataUri?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, canvas, drawimage, data-uri

I am trying to search if there is a way to convert a piece of a canvas to a dataURI. 
Right now I have

```
canvas.drawImage(canvas, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh);
data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

the drawimage gets called hundreds, maybe thousands of times and it's very expensive time-wise. If this step could be skipped it could significant speed things up.

Any thoughts or ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, why don't you just skip it then?  Are you not waiting until all the `canvas.drawImage()`s are done before converting to a data url?  What do you mean by a piece?  Do you only want a portion of your canvas converted?

Comment: Isn't it some kind of duplicate of [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639839/convert-piece-of-canvas-to-blob-type)?

Comment: the drawimage only get a piece of the canvas. I still want the data uri but not from the entire canvas