# Canvas.toDataURL() on Cordova || Cordova to work Multithreaded

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, canvas

I am currently working on an hybrid app for android which should record videos just like in Vine and Instagram. It's all good to this point. All of my code works perfectly stable on desktop or notebooks.

But when it comes to Cordova with Crosswalk Project WebView embedded, canvas.toDataURL() becomes a big trouble.

I do not know if WebView multithreaded but canvas.toDataURL()'s performance is terrible on mobile phones. It just takes too much ram/cpu. Because of that video recording fps drops to 3~5.

Is there any other solutions that I could use to get dataURL from canvas? OR tell Cordova/javascript to work multithreaded on webView.

Thanks

Comment: If you are using native plugin to capture image then reducing the quality of image while capturing may help by some extent. Accepted answer in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3952856/why-is-putimagedata-so-slow) may help too...

Comment: @RayonDabre nope, i am not using native plugin. I am using HTML5 Web RTC. (navigator.webkitGetUserMedia)

Comment: They must be having some argument to control the media I suppose. It is so useful as we may have to deal with 50% weight of actual image(depends on the requirement of image quality though)